# Windows Phone 8 Map Overlay/Region

Tags: maps, windows-phone

In Windows Phone 8, using the Map control, is it possible to place a region or an overlay on top of the map that covers a certain area? Let's say for example i wish to cover the entire area of London with an overlay of some sort... the colour blue for example...

Would this be at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. The basic steps are:

1. Create a new `MapPolygon` instance (in your example this instance will be used to define the geographical boundaries of London as well as the color you want to use for the overlay)
2. Add the `GeoCoordinate` instances that define the geographical boundaries (i.e. the lat/long coordinates) for each point that defines the geographical area you want to cover to the `Path` property on your `MapPolygon` instance
3. Set the properties you want for the polygon (fill color, stroke color, etc)
4. Add your `MapPolygon` instance (created in step 1) to your map control's `MapElements` property.

You can also draw regular lines on the map using the `MapPolyline` class and get more fancy and put any control on top of the map (e.g. images representing various information) using the `MapLayer` and `MapOverlay` classes.